# PyTorch Error loading "\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, shap

I cannot use PyTorch and Shap getting this error

```
PyTorch Error loading  "\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I have tried

- to uninstall and re-install PyTorch, failed
- create a new conda environment and reinstalled everything including PyTorch, failed
- to install .NET C++ as suggested in other posts, but it was already installed

I am not an expert on SO and dependencies, but i find it strange that there is not an easy way to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: How are you installing?

Comment: Does `\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll` exist? Do you have sufficient privileges to load it?

Comment: I use the suggested instructions for installing found in Anaconda website. The dll exists. I have fixed it just installing a third new conda environment. But I don't know what is changed between all these attempts. The only thing could be a different installation sequence even if I find it so strange.

Answer (score 10):

I manage to get past the error by `conda install cudatoolkit`

Answer (score 1):

i fixed Error loading "torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies

use : `conda install cudatoolkit`

if still getting the above error after running the above command. you should restart the computer and then turn on anaconda again.

I would be happy if I could help