WinError 126: The specified module could not be found
I am trying to use torch and ultralytics library using pip but I am getting this error
 Error loading "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\torch\lib\shm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Please, help me. I am over 6 yours trying to solve it.

Please add a code example causing this error

import torch

You can check this solution with conda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74594256/pytorch-error-loading-lib-site-packages-torch-lib-shm-dll-or-one-of-its-depen.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187161/error-while-import-pytorch-module-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Update: I uninstalled python and reinstalled it using conda and the problem is no more.

The quickest fix would be to replace these added lines in this github post in torch package's init.py

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
